# XML/XSLT: How to add attribute to element

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, element

I need a nudge in the right direction on using XSLT to transform XML to XML.

This is my source XML:

```
<Master>
 <Camera CamID="007" Name="Cammie">
      <CameraUptime Uptime="20"/>
      <Detection Total="400">
        <Phase phase1="40" phase2="0" phase3="160">XYZ</Phase>
        <Phase phase1="180" phase2="20" phase3="0">XYZ</Phase>
      </Detection>
  </Camera>
  <Camera CamID="099" Name="Saturn">
      <CameraUptime Uptime="20"/>
      <Detection Total="4000">
        <Phase phase1="400" phase2="0" phase3="1600">XYZ</Phase>
      </Detection>
  </Camera>
</Master>
```

Using XSL I have been able to add 'ParentNode' to the  element, See XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Phase">
    <ParentNode>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </ParentNode>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Master>
  <Camera CamID="007" Name="Cammie">
    <CameraUptime Uptime="20" />
    <Detection Total="400">
      <ParentNode>
        <Phase phase1="40" phase2="0" phase3="160">XYZ</Phase>
      </ParentNode>
      <ParentNode>
        <Phase phase1="180" phase2="20" phase3="0">XYZ</Phase>
      </ParentNode>
    </Detection>
  </Camera>
  <Camera CamID="099" Name="Saturn">
    <CameraUptime Uptime="20" />
    <Detection Total="4000">
      <ParentNode>
        <Phase phase1="400" phase2="0" phase3="1600">XYZ</Phase>
      </ParentNode>
    </Detection>
  </Camera>
</Master>
```

I now need to add the correct CamID to the 'Phase' element. The output should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Master>
  <Camera CamID="007" Name="Cammie">
    <CameraUptime Uptime="20" />
    <Detection Total="400">
      <ParentNode>
        <Phase phase1="40" phase2="0" phase3="160" CamID="007">XYZ</Phase>
      </ParentNode>
      <ParentNode>
        <Phase phase1="180" phase2="20" phase3="0" CamID="007">XYZ</Phase>
      </ParentNode>
    </Detection>
  </Camera>
  <Camera CamID="099" Name="Saturn">
    <CameraUptime Uptime="20" />
    <Detection Total="4000">
      <ParentNode>
        <Phase phase1="400" phase2="0" phase3="1600" CamID="099">XYZ</Phase>
      </ParentNode>
    </Detection>
  </Camera>
</Master>
```

Any tips on how to proceed are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply change:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
```

in the template matching `Phase` to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|ancestor::Camera/@CamID"" />
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that was what I was looking for :) It's quite clear I'm in need of some schooling on the subject. I'm thinking of purchasing this book:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527211.do
Any other literary suggestions?

Comment: I am afraid I am not the right person to ask (self-taught).